# i want my bottom widget to push on top when keyboard focused

Tags: flutter

i want my bottom widget to push on top when keyboard focused because it hide the the bottom widget please help me how can i resolve and i have some more widgets but i want to my bottom widget to  show up on screen

```
body: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 0),
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Align(),
                Padding()
                Container(),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                GestureDetector(),
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Text.rich(
                  TextSpan(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include `resizeToAvoidBottomInset:true` it is will shrink the size on keyboard appear(default).

If you use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` wrap the body with scollable widget. like

```
body: SingleChildScrollView( child:  Column(...
```

To check keyboard visibility, you can check [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility) and and use a scrollController to move bottom.

```dart
 return KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
      builder: (context, isKeyboardVisible) {
         if (isKeyboardVisible){
            controller.animateTo(
        controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
        curve: Curves.bounceIn,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100)
       );
      }
     return ListView(
              controller: controller,
            ),
  );
```